# String that is saved in config file on parse webpage ignores newline characters when later user in text field in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, newline

In my iOS app im using parse and its feature called Config.
In config file is saved a string: \nTESTSend via XY\nYou can get the app ...

And later on I user this string in UITextField which should translate \n as a newline. But actually it justi print it as a normal text.

Are there any ideas what should I try. On iOS newline can be make by putting \n in the string content.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I use UITextView allready. Its actually MFMessageComposeViewController which includes UITextView.

Comment: No, I didnt change anything. I'm using UITextView from the beginning, so the problem is still the same.

Comment: I tried that and it print \\n insted of going into new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you.Set the text property as like below.

```
textView.text = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
```